# Pandas Dataframe to .csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

**Code**:

```
def print_data(data, dataframe):
      print('%3d | %s | %s, %s, %s, %s, %s'
            % (len(dataframe), data['Symbol'],
               pd.to_datetime(int(data['Updated']), unit='ms'),
               data['Rates'][0], data['Rates'][1], data['Rates'][2],
               data['Rates'][3]))
```

**Output of Code**:

```
8 | EUR/USD | 2019-05-22 14:03:21.475000, 1.1162, 1.11632, 1.11809, 1.11481
```

i want to save this output in an csv file

Comment: Check out [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: if i try with: df.to_csv(test, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8') i get: NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Comment: What is the variable of your dataframe?  Is it data?  Try `data.to_csv(...`

Comment: The def print_data

Answer (score 2):

`data.to_csv("data.csv", sep = ",")`

Comment: would work but its just working for 1 line - but the stream is updating every ms

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'